# Its my first servlet program and I have issues

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

My index looks like this:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<title> JSP Servlet Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center" style="margin-top: 50px;">

    <form action="ServletManager">
        Please enter your Username:  <input type="text" name="username" size="20px"> <br>
        Please enter your Password:  <input type="text" name="password" size="20px"> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</HTML>
```

My servlet:

```
package helloweb;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;



public class ServletManager extends HttpServlet {protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // reading the user input
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println (
        "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" +" +
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" +
        "<html> \n" +
        "<head> \n" +
        "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; " +
        "charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" +
        "<title> JSP Servlet Example  </title> \n" +
        "</head> \n" +
        "<body> <div align='center'> \n" +
            "<style= \"font-size=\"12px\" color='black'\"" + "\">" +
            "Username: " + username + " <br> " +
            "Password: " + password +
            "</font></body> \n" +
        "</html>"
            );
        }
    }
```

My XML:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
    JSPServletExample

```
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>helloweb.ServletManager</servlet-class>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ServletManager.java</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is my issue:

Firefox can’t find the file at /C:/Users/HP/IdeaProjects/ourdemo                                             /web/ServletManager?username=hello&password=hello.`

I host at the tomcat 7 server.

The first page appears. I type in the username and password, and I get this.
Please help.

Comment: Please note that this approach is entirely obsolete; unless this is for a class that has not been updated in 20 years, you should use a Web framework like Spring MVC that handles most of this for you (and in that case, you should also use Spring Security to handle the security pieces like user login).

Comment: First open the JSP by http:// URL and not by a file:// URL. Then fix your form action and servlet mapping conform the instructions in the abovelinked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the url pattern change this in web.xml from /ServletManager.java to /ServletManager and try
https://javabelazy.blogspot.com/2010/02/student-registration-form-in-java.html (Working code)